# Какая асимптотика поиска элемента по ключу у пирамиды?

Tags: алгоритм

Поиск в пирамиде по ключу ведь происходит за O(log n) ведь мы же знаем, что у пирамиды каждый ребёнок (или больше или меньше родителя)?

Comment: Поиск по ключу в пирамиде требует `O(n)`, где `n` - размер пирамиды.

Comment: @gbg Сначала поставил плюсик комменту, а потом задумался, полез в Кормена. Расскажите, как именно *искать* в пирамиде за O(log n)? Не сортировать за O(n log n), а именно искать?